# identifying event on Tableview controller and also Tabbar controller?

Tags: iphone

i have two questions here..?

if i scroll my tableview,how can i identify it...is there any method to identify it?
any help please?

if i touch already selected Tab bar item ,can i identify it?
any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableview conforms to the UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol therefore in your tableview delegate class you can respond to

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
```

UITabBar can also have a delegate method that you can override so you can simply do something like:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

if (tabBar.selectedItem == item)
   {
     //tabBar button has been pressed but is already selected so do something.
   } 
}
```